# how to sync my university email to my Android?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I bought a new galaxy s4 and I can't sync my university account to the cell phone. I tried going to settings>>accounts>>add account>>email but I still can't connect it.

my email is something like this *****@mail.university.ac.il

Answer (score 6):

This question is impossible to answer without knowing the configuration your university uses. You should ask for the details of the mail server from the university's helpdesk. You'll need to know at least the server address, username and password for your mail account, and possibly even more details such as custom port numbers, access restrictions, protocols to use, encryption etc.

I'm certain that the helpdesk can assist you in getting the email settings correctly into your phone.

Comment: Can you explain to me where can I find such things ?

Comment: From your university's help desk or IT support.